# Help understand truth value of $\exists !\,x\;P(x) \implies \exists x\;P(x)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Can someone help me understand this logic problem:

What are the truth values of these statements?

a) $\exists !\,x\;P(x) \implies \exists x\;P(x)$

b) $\forall x\;P(x) \implies\exists !x\;P(x)$

c) $\exists!x\;\neg P(x) \implies \neg\forall x\;P(x)$

Correct answer (from the book answers):

a) true

b) false

c) true

The way I am see a) for example is:

1. "There is a unique x for which if $P(x)$ then there exists another $x$ for which $P(x)$"
2. $\exists !\,x\;P(x)$ can be broken down to just $P(x)$ since there is a "unique $x$"
3. $\exists x\;P(x)$ can be broken down to: $P(x_1) \lor P(x_2) \lor ... \lor P(x_n)$
4. Therefore at step #2, if the unique $x$ is FALSE, then the entire statement is TRUE (according to the truth table for $\implies$)
5. If #2 is TRUE, then step #3 must have at list 1 TRUE $P(x_i)$ for the overall statement to be true,
6. Therefore I see it can be both TRUE and FALSE depending on $x$. I am not sure how the book comes to true. I don't fully understand this. Can someone correct me and fill my gap in understanding there. Similar issues in understanding b) and c) as well...

Thank you!

Comment: ad 1: strike "another"

Comment: The truth of b) depends on the universe, which *may* have only one object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. "There is a unique x for which if P(x) then there exists another x for which P(x)"

No. It does not specify that the second $x$ is an *other* $x$. Also, you make the $\exists !$ to be the main operator of the statement (i.e. you interpret it as $\exists ! x (P(x) \rightarrow \exists x P(x))$  but the main operator is the conditional. So, it says: "If there is exactly one object with property $P$, then there is at least one object with property $P$

> 2. "∃!xP(x)" can be broken down to just "P(x)" since there is a "unique x"

No. $P(x)$ is not a claim; it is a formula with a free variable.

> 3. "∃xP(x)" can be broken down to: "P(x1) ⋁ P(x2) ⋁ ... ⋁ P(xn)"

... *informally* that's ok .. but be careful!  ... This is assuming $x_1, ..., x_n$ are all the objects in the domain. And they are all constants referring to those objects.

> 4. Therefore at step #2, if the unique x is FALSE, then the entire statement is TRUE (according to the truth table for "->")

you don't phrase this very well ('the unique x is FALSE'... ?! .. objects aren't false ...) ... I assume you mean: "If there is no unique object with property $x$, then the whole conditional is true". And yes, that is so.

> 5. If #2 is TRUE, then step #3 must have at list 1 TRUE P(xi) for the overall statement to be true

yes ..

> 6. Therefore I see it can be both TRUE and FALSE depending on x.

Huh?  So you just reasoned that if there is *not* a unique object with property $P$, then the statement is TRUE, and if there *is* such a unique object, then the statement is *also* TRUE ... so how come you say that it could be FALSE or TRUE?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my derailments! After analyzing your comments I feel basic understanding on why a) is T. Also see why b) is false unless domain size of 1, and  c) is true.

Comment: @jox Great! And yes, those answers are all correct. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is too convoluted.   Just read the statements.

> $\exists !x~P(x)\implies \exists x~P(x)$ : "*If* $P$ holds for exactly one thing, *then* $P$ holds for something."

Quantfied variables in different scopes *may* (or may not) refer to the same entities.   They need not be different entities.   (There is no "another" in the statement.)

An entailment is falsified *exactly when* the consequent may be false while the antecedant is true.

So *may* it be false that "$P$ holds for something" *if it is true* that "$P$ holds for exactly one thing"?

---

> $\forall x~P(x)\implies \exists!x~P(x)$ : "*If* $P$ holds for everything, *then* $P$ holds for exactly one thing."

---

> $\exists !x~\neg P(x)\implies \neg\forall x~P(x)$ : "*If* $P$ doesn't hold for exactly one thing, *then* $P$ holds for not every thing ."